# Objective C: Class Method Explanation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

As a part of my transition process from C++ to Objective-C, I intensively read book [Cocoa and Objective C Up and Running.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804792)

In one of the book code examples, there is a line that does not make sense to me with my current level of knowledge:

It is a declaration of class method `+ (Photo*) photo;`.

Could anybody explain me the reason, please, why the author had decided for the method `(Photo*) photo;` to declare it as a **class method** instead of **instance method**?

I have studiet the theory, that the instane method is something like a **class member function** and that class method is something like **static function** in C++. But this still does not answer my question.

*Here is the declaration code:*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Photo : NSObject{

    NSString* caption;
    NSString* photographer;    
}

+ (Photo*) photo;

- (NSString*) caption;
- (NSString*) photographer;

- (void) setCaption: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setPhotographer: (NSString*)input;

@end
```

*The implementation code follows:*

```
#import "Photo.h"


@implementation Photo

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setCaption:@"Default Caption"];
        [self setPhotographer:@"Default Photographer"];
    }

    return self;
}


+ (Photo*) photo {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}


- (NSString*) caption {
    return caption;
}


- (NSString*) photographer {
    return photographer;
}


- (void) setCaption:(NSString *)input {
    [caption autorelease];
    caption = [input retain];
}


- (void) setPhotographer: (NSString *)input {
    [photographer autorelease];
    photographer = [input retain];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [self setCaption:nil];
    [self setPhotographer:nil];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: That method declaration, interestingly, is incorrect. All initializers should return `id`, and constructors should use `self` (which refers to the class inside a class method), not the hard-coded class name. These two things are necessary in order for subclassing to work properly. EDIT: I see that bbum has already mentioned this below, but I think it bears repeating.

Comment: @Josh Exactly;  expanded in a meta-answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anybody explain me the reason, please, why the author had decided for the method (Photo*) photo; to declare it as a class method instead of instance method?

It's basically a wrapper of the constructor litany. Note the source:

```
+ (Photo*) photo {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

Allocate a new Photo, initialize it, mark it autorelease, and return it. Since it creates the object, there is no object yet to operate upon, ergo this needs to be a class method.

Comment: +1, hi Mike. Perfectly explained. Thank you. So if I understand correctly, it is one of very few cases when a method id declared as a class method, instead as instance method.

Comment: Despite all of the answers were correct, I think, this one explained my question in the clearest way. As I can chose only one answer as the *Accepted Answer*, I would like to mark this one.

Comment: One issue; that method should be declared as returning `id` and should `return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];` (one line or two, doesn't matter -- just should refer to the Class directly).  As it is, `Photo` is gonna be a pain to subclass.

Comment: @bbum: Please elaborate on "`Photo` is gonna be a pain to subclass." I'm new to Obj-C myself and would like some insight.

Answer (score 7):

The `+ (Photo*) photo` method is a [Factory Method](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) that encapsulates the details of creating an object of the `Photo` class.

> A Factory Method enforces
>   encapsulation, and allows an object to
>   be requested without inextricable
>   coupling to the act of creation.

In this particular example the information being hidden by the factory method is [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), since the client does not need to worry about releasing the returned object.

It is a **common practice in Objective-C APIs to provide factory methods in classes that return autoreleased objects of that same classes**. These methods must not contain any of the words “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, which, according to the convention, indicates that the caller doesn't own the returned object, i.e. it doesn't have to be explicitly released.

**Related resources:**

- [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Answer (score 4):

Meta answer:

> One issue; that method should be
>   declared as returning id and should
>   return [[[self alloc] init]
>   autorelease]; (one line or two,
>   doesn't matter -- just should refer to
>   the Class directly). As it is, Photo
>   is gonna be a pain to subclass.

Expanding -- given this:

```
+ (Photo*) photo {
    Photo* newPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

If the class were subclassed, this factory method would not work without being overridden to do pretty much the same thing.  However, since Objective-C doesn't support co-variance and contra-variance, there would be no way to declare the subclass's implementation of `+photo` to return an instance of the subclass without also running a significant risk of compiler warnings.  Alternatively, you could down-cast the return value to the more specific class, but that is rife with fragility.

Instead, do this:

```
+ (id) photo {
    id newPhoto = [[self alloc] init];
    return [newPhoto autorelease];
}
```

This fixes both issues:

- since it uses `self`, it'll instantiate an instance of whatever class it is implemented on, including subclasses of `Photo`.
- since it returns `id`, callers can do both of the following without issue:

  Photo *p = [Photo photo];
  SubclassOfPhoto *s = [SubclassOfPhoto photo];

Comment: Thus making `photo` a true factory method, in that subclasses don't need to define their own versions.

Comment: Exactly;  as it is, it is a factory hardwired to a particular class.   Not so good for Class clusters and other similar patterns.

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, `photo` is a convenience method, which returns you an `autoreleased` instance of the class.

Since the purpose of photo is to give you an instance, it wouldn't make sense to make it an instance method which would require you to already have an instance.

If you're familiar with Factory Methods, the photo method is similar to that.

Comment: +1 -Hi Michael. Perfectly explained on your side, and understood on mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`+photo` is like a constructor. You need a way to get an object to send instance methods to, and this gives you an autoreleased one.

Comment: +1, Hi Jeremy, thanks for your answer. What would happen, if I declare the method as an instance method? would I be able to create objects with it, please?

Comment: No, because you would have a chicken and egg problem: How do you get an instance of the object to send the instance method to? In that case, your `-photo` instance method would be more like `-copy` or `-clone` in spirit than a constructor.

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you Jeremy.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to a static method, as you say. In this case (and all cases of `[ClassName className]` methods) it's basically a **factory method**. You're asking the class to construct an instance of itself and pass it back. All such methods should return an autoreleased object.

You can safely ignore methods like that if you want - there will usually be an alloc+init equivalent, but it's often more convenient to use the class method, especially if you're creating a throaway object and don't want to retain it.

Finally, you'll sometimes find classes which *require* you to use the class method, as they'll hide some clever logic wherein an instance of *another* class is actually returned. You'll sometimes hear these described as 'class clusters'.

Comment: A class cluster can handle the standard alloc-init dance just fine. It's just that `-init` will almost certainly return a different object than `-alloc`. See, for example, `NSString` or `NSArray`, where alloc-init works fine to construct a new instance.

Comment: +1 -Hi Thom, and thanks for your explanation. You even provided a bit more useful information. I understood what you said.